# Why "gmail.com" and "www.gmail.com" IPs navigate me to "google.com" homepage?

Tags: internet, ip, gmail, ping

As you see below I get a ping of www.gmail.com and gmail.com :

```
C:\>ping www.gmail.com

Pinging googlemail.l.google.com [74.125.232.149] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.232.149: bytes=32 time=118ms TTL=49
Reply from 74.125.232.149: bytes=32 time=119ms TTL=49
Reply from 74.125.232.149: bytes=32 time=118ms TTL=49
Reply from 74.125.232.149: bytes=32 time=124ms TTL=49

Ping statistics for 74.125.232.149:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 118ms, Maximum = 124ms, Average = 119ms

C:\>ping gmail.com

Pinging gmail.com [173.194.39.213] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 173.194.39.213: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=51
Reply from 173.194.39.213: bytes=32 time=92ms TTL=51
Reply from 173.194.39.213: bytes=32 time=92ms TTL=51
Reply from 173.194.39.213: bytes=32 time=92ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for 173.194.39.213:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 92ms, Maximum = 93ms, Average = 92ms

C:\>
```

Q1: Why I received two different IP? (I think www.gmail.com is the same gmail.com, Isn't it?)

Q2: Why When I use these IPs to open Gmail homepage, I navigated to google homepage? (Try them)

Q3: What is *gmail* IP? can I open gmail homepage using an IP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship between a fqdn (a web address) and an IP address can be many to many.

In that many different IP addresses can serve the same websites, and a single IP address can serve many different websites.

When a webserver at an IP address is hosting multiple websites, it uses headers in the request sent from your browser to know which site to send back.

In the absence of a header saying which website is requested, there is often a default one.  In Google's case, if a specific site is not requested from a server, it returns the Google search website.

Google has infrastructure world wide, with thousands of servers hosting google.com, gmail.com all its other web assets.  This infrastructure changes on a daily basis depending on demand.

If for some reason you cannot use DNS to request gmail.com, your option is to edit your `hosts` file and add an entry for gmail (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)

Edit `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Add

```
173.194.39.213 gmail.com
```

You may need to add others in case GMail brings in content from other domain names.

Then you can access gmail.com on

```
https://gmail.com
```